# Filter tableView rows doesn't reload tableView

Tags: ios, swift, filter, tableview

My first iOS app works with simple custom cells, but enhancement to filter  tableView rows is causing delays and frustration.   Searched online for help on filter rows, read dataSource and delegate protocols in Apple Developer guides, no luck so far.

Using slider value to refresh table rows. Extracted data from line array (100 items) to `linefilter` array (20). Then want to refresh/reload the tableview.

Slider is declared with 0 and all line array items show up. moving the slider does not alter display. If slider is declared with say 1, then 20 filter items show.

Quite new to Apple/Xcode/Swift so have no Objective C knowledge.

Any answers will probably help me get there.
Jim L

Relevant selection of code :

```
 @IBAction func moveSlider(sender: AnyObject) {
      // Non-continuous  ******
        _ = false
      // integer 0 to 5  ******
        let slider = Int(lineSlider.value)
        }
    }

 // Global Variable   ******
 var slider = 0

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        if slider == 0  {        
            return self.line.count
        } else  {  
           return self.linefilter.count
        }
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {        
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! myTableViewCell
        if slider == 0  {
            cell.myCellLabel.text = line[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            cell.myCellLabel.text = linefilter[indexPath.row]
        }
        cell.myImageView.image = UIImage(named: img[indexPath.row])
        return cell          
    }
    tableView.reloadata()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to put

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

like this

```
let slider = Int(lineSlider.value)
     tableView.reloadData()
}
```

in your moveSlider function

Comment: Hi, thanks but no luck, I tried reload in several places too.

Comment: i'dont see your filtering code, after calling reloadData() did you check if code goes to cell.myCellLabel.text = linefilter[indexPath.row] or to cell.myCellLabel.text = line[indexPath.row]?

Comment: Found an issue, in the if - else code, slider value does not update when slider changes value, it retains initial value 0. The filter code is called in the moveSlider action, but too much code to would hide the fault.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your helpful comments. It's now working and reloading the tableview as wanted. JimL.

Comment: great to hear about that, have a nice day :)